# Display images in gridview ,zoom the images and swipe images with animation

Tags: android, android-image, android-gridview, zooming

Want an example to display the drawable images in grid view and after clicking on the particular image it zoom(display full) and want an animation to swipe the images with this zoom images.

Comment: For that case you can use TouchImageView class and also viewFlipper for swipe your images.

Comment: see this links http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/  http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/06/making-sense-of-multitouch.html

Comment: If you have any example please refer to me..I tried this..http://www.androidhive.info/2013/09/android-fullscreen-image-slider-with-swipe-and-pinch-zoom-gestures/..bt getting eoor

Comment: Nothing is displayed here